# mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking

Tags: linux, networking, debian, mount, autofs

I am trying to mount a disk from a remote computer but I get this error:

```
root@sidibalkan:~# mount -t nfs rat:/develop /mnt
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

I am running Debian 7. The remote server is running Debian 5. Any idea why this happens? If I add the extra argument it works but the problem is that I want to mount it automatically via autofs. Strangely enough I can mount disks from another server (which runs Debian 7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the `nolock` argument in the /etc/auto.rat file and now it works with autofs too.

Answer (score 15):

```
systemctl start rpc-statd
```

or

```
service rpcbind start
service nfs-common start
```

then your NFS mounts will work.

Comment: Although I answered this question 7 years ago, today I was trying to use a client inside an ubuntu inside a docker, and this double `service` thing made it work. I just had to run those lines inside the docker container before doing the mount.

Comment: I was trying to connect to an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I set up an NFS mount on VM, then on the Linux guest ran `systemctl start rcp-statd` and viola! I was able to connect to the VM from my Mac host

Comment: systemctl start rpc-statd worked for me, I was having some lockd not responding errors

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem and was because the client tried to connect locally to its own rpc.

I had to add `127.0.0.1` to my `/etc/hosts.allow` in the client machine.

For my session copied below, those are the involved data:

- `guarra` is the name of the client machine.
- `192.168.2.53` the server (named `fluor` but this name is not used here).
- `/files` is the exported share from the server.
- `/files/fluor` is the destination to mount it on.

A shell session pre-modification:

```
root@guarra:/files# cat /etc/hosts.allow
rpcbind : 192.168.2.0/24
root@guarra:/files# mount 192.168.2.53:/files fluor/
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
root@guarra:/files#
```

I modified the file and got this:

```
root@guarra:/files# cat /etc/hosts.allow
rpcbind : 192.168.2.0/24 127.0.0.1
root@guarra:/files# mount 192.168.2.53:/files fluor/
root@guarra:/files#
```

After adding the local IP to the client, it could use it's own rpc, as you can see, the error message disappeared and I could mount the remote share properly.

Comment: Thanks, adding 127.0.0.1 to hosts.allow for the rpcbind service solved this problem for me on Ubuntu 16.04, autofs now mounts nfs shares automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had problems with servers where the loopback interface was removed. In that case, traffic tries to go over to the regular (say `eth0`) interface and times out.

The solution in that case is to restore the loopback interface, which probably looks something like this (Debian Wheezy 7.6):

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS_Troubleshooting

> To fix this, you need to change the "NEED_STATD" value in /etc/conf.d/nfs-common.conf to YES.

Comment: I can't find this file on my system but I set the value of NEED_STATD to both yes and no in /etc/init.d/nfs-common and it doesn't help.

Comment: This is a bad answer because 1) I suspect this is for only Arch Linux and 2) it doesn't provide an example of the full code (ie. `NEED_STATD=yes` or `NEED_STATD yes`

Answer (score 0):

start rpcbind and nfslock services.[reference](https://backdrift.org/fixing-rpc-statd-running-required-remote-locking)

```
/etc/init.d/rpcbind start
/etc/init.d/nfslock start
```